# How to wait for a connection asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I've designed a class which wraps a `Socket` and allows sending and receiving through/from it.  Since accepting, sending and receiving are done through the UI, I don't want them to block it thus I used their asynchronous versions.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public void Accept()
{
     // ...
     // where resultAccept is a IAsyncResult
    resultAccept = listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    connectedSocket = listener.EndAccept(ar);
}

public string Receive()
{
    char[] data = new char[128];

    if (!resultAccept.IsCompleted) // (1)
        resultAccept.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    connectedSocket.BeginReceive(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                 new AsyncCallback(RecvCallback), null);

    // ...
}
```

When I start receiving, since there's no connection yet, it has to wait for one (1) and blocks the UI (which, again, I don't want).
In addition, when a connection is accepted I get a `NullReferenceException` because when `BeginReceive` starts, `AcceptCallback` is, yes triggered, but has not completed yet so `connectedSocket` still has to be initialized.

1. **Why is my approach wrong?**
2. **Is it possible to achieve what I want with async sockets?**
3. **How can I prevent the UI from blocking while waiting for a connection and ensuring the validity of the object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, because you are blocking. You need to throw that away.
2. Yes, there are `Socket` extension methods on the web that adapt the obsolete APM pattern to the TAP pattern so that you can use await. The exercise becomes trivial then.

Your code should look like:

```
async Task RunServer() {
 Socket serverSocket = ...;

 while (true) {
  RunConnection(await serverSocket.AcceptAsync());
 }
}
```

And then provide a `Task RunConnectionAsync(Socket s)` function that is async as well. Really simple once you leave the obsolete APM pattern alone.

Alternatively, just use threads and synchronous IO. Nothing wrong with doing that. `await` is a little nicer, though, because it marshals back to the UI thread for you automatically.

Comment: But what's wrong then with async sockets if a thread + sync IO would work?

Comment: You mean why anyone would use them? Async saves threads and it makes it easier to work with the UI thread. Besides that there is (almost) no reason to go async but there are reasons not to. Async is a fad right now. Also most socket tutorials are embarrassingly wrong.

Comment: Ah, so what I'm using right now is even obsolete. Anyways, you said " just use threads and synchronous IO" so I was wondering why wouldn't asynchronous sockets be able to get it done if a thread + synchronous sockets could, which is what an asynchronous socket does under the hood. Hope you can see what I mean.

Comment: Async sockets do "get it done" as well. Did I create a wrong impression? It's not important for the question but async IO does not use threads while it runs. An IO is just a data structure in the OS kernel.

Comment: Well, your answer appears to impose a solution with TAP. Since I can get the same result with APM (as you said), I'd prefer that, if possible.
My concern is to understand what's causing those issues and fixing it, maybe by not changing the code radically.

Comment: The Task sockets API (as suggested) is just a thin wrapper around the APM. Same efficiency, same non-blocking behavior. Just nice to consume. You can of course also use APM if you like. Then you have to devise a scheme of callbacks that does what the sample code in my answer does. The code explodes by 10x. But there is zero reason to use APM if you can use TAP.

Comment: I've read that asynchronous sockets were actually thought to work along with UI code, so that it doesn't block by "default"; this drives me crazy. A simple problem, like mine, cannot benefit from that. Weird. I must be missing something, and that little thing requires me to use another technology which, although surely better, won't misplace it.

Comment: If you like APM go ahead. It's ugly, that is the only problem. And you need to remove the event that you used in the question code snippet. Had Task existed in .NET 1.0 the APM pattern would not exist. Actually I don't see what's weird here. The event is the bug in your code and TAP would be a stylistic non-functional improvement.